# magnolia blossom spring security login

Tags: spring, spring-security, magnolia

I am able to create a project using Blossom module. I create a login template to provide login function for my site using spring security.

I am not able to submit my request to j_spring_security_check .it's keep on saying 404 not found.

How I can include this login functionality using spring security  in blossom magnolia?

**ADDED WEB.XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
version="2.5">
<description>Magnolia</description>
<display-name>magnolia</display-name>
<distributable />

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>info.magnolia.module.blossom.web.InstallationAwareDelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter>
    <display-name>Magnolia global filters</display-name>
    <filter-name>magnoliaFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlMainFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>magnoliaFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>info.magnolia.init.MagnoliaServletContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/spring-database.xml,
        /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Spring Security -->
<context-param>
    <description>Vaadin production mode</description>
    <param-name>productionMode</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>heartbeatInterval</param-name>
    <param-value>90</param-value>
</context-param>
<!-- These are the default paths searched for magnolia configuration. Uncomment 
    if you need to customize these. Your container might also do its own variables 
    substitution here. Tomcat, for instance, allows you to use system properties, 
    such as ${user.home}. -->
<!-- <context-param> <param-name>magnolia.initialization.file</param-name> 
    <param-value> WEB-INF/config/${servername}/${contextPath}/magnolia.properties, 
    WEB-INF/config/${servername}/${webapp}/magnolia.properties, WEB-INF/config/${servername}/magnolia.properties, 
    WEB-INF/config/${contextPath}/magnolia.properties, WEB-INF/config/${webapp}/magnolia.properties, 
    WEB-INF/config/default/magnolia.properties, WEB-INF/config/magnolia.properties 
    </param-value> </context-param> -->
<jsp-config>
    <jsp-property-group>
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
        <page-encoding>UTF-8</page-encoding>
    </jsp-property-group>
</jsp-config>
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/docroot/404.html</location>
</error-page>
```

When Tried with the  second alternate solution.it's throwing an following error and no pages are getting loaded

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
```

Comment: have you configured your web.xml as shown here https://wiki.magnolia-cms.com/display/WIKI/Using+Spring+Security+with+Magnolia+and+Blossom

Comment: Daniele,I have created blossom project using https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/Getting+started+with+Blossom. Web.xml is getting generated once I ran maven install.So how can I make my maven install to add this filter in generated web.xml?

Comment: btw your link is broken, however you have to modify the web.xml under your webapp project, it won't be never overriden.

Comment: sorry, link is https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/Getting+started+with+Blossom  . When we run maven clean , all the target items are getting cleared.

Comment: alright, have you updated the web xml in the webapp? Does it work now?

Comment: Daniele, added in xml and when submit the loginform it's saying 404 page not found for both /j_spring_security_check {contextPath}/j_spring_security_check

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73906/discussion-between-sree-and-daniele).

Comment: another think that you should consider is that your security filter should be called before the magnolia filter chain, hope it helps

Comment: from Web.xml , we can see that the first filter is the spring security filter. So it is calling before the magnolia filter.

Comment: can you try the second alternative here https://wiki.magnolia-cms.com/display/WIKI/Using+Spring+Security+with+Magnolia+and+Blossom and be sure that the order of the filters is the same as shown in the picture, does it work?

Comment: I tried the alternate approach and seems like the filter is calling but getting invoked infinite times. added the error to the ticket

Comment: well, have you deleted that filter from the web xml before to update the filter chain in magnolia?

Comment: and I would try also the alternative 1, but deleting all the dispatcher tags in filter-mapping

Comment: yaa..I removed it from web.xml and then added filter in magnolia. I will try alternative 1 by removing dispatcher tags and will see

Comment: I removed dispatchers for magnoliaFilterChain and tired it but still it is saying 404 url not found